# Not able to run automation script on real device

Tags: android, eclipse, ipad, safari, appium

I'm new to appium and eclipse and i'm trying to run simple script on device. I have added the UDID and created a provisioning profile. Few days back the scripts were running fine, but suddenly today the safari launcher application on my iPad started crashing too. When i re-install the safari launcher and when i try to run the script is get the below listed error, has anyone faced similar issue?

```
 2016-09-16 11:57:44:131 - [debug] [Instruments] Attempting to launch instruments, this is try #1
    2016-09-16 11:57:44:131 - [Instruments] Launching instruments
    2016-09-16 11:57:44:135 - [debug] [Instruments] Attempting to run app on real device with UDID 'd83c88477a911a053e5de26036fe8b0512e3d0e6'
    2016-09-16 11:57:44:137 - [debug] [Instruments] Found Insruments-Without-Delay: /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-ios-driver/node_modules/appium-instruments/thirdparty/iwd7
    2016-09-16 11:57:44:138 - [debug] [Instruments] Spawning instruments with command: '"/Applications/Xcode 4.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/instruments" -t "/Applications/Xcode 4.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.xrplugin/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate" -D /var/folders/py/kgvfbnsd4dl8xvx3nktsh6p00000gn/T/appium-instruments/instrumentscli0.trace -w d83c88477a911a053e5de26036fe8b0512e3d0e6 com.bytearc.SafariLauncher -e UIASCRIPT "/Users/vbs/Library/Application Support/appium/bootstrap/bootstrap-bcf5a832c5089d74.js" -e UIARESULTSPATH /var/folders/py/kgvfbnsd4dl8xvx3nktsh6p00000gn/T/appium-instruments'
    2016-09-16 11:57:44:138 - [debug] [Instruments] And extra without-delay env: {}
    2016-09-16 11:57:44:138 - [debug] [Instruments] And launch timeouts (in ms): {"global":90000}

    2016-09-16 11:57:44:996 - [HTTP] <-- GET /wd/hub/status - - ms - - 

    2016-09-16 11:57:45:079 - [debug] [Instruments] [INST STDERR] 2016-09-16 11:57:45.079 instruments[895:15838] WebKit Threading Violation - initial use of WebKit from a secondary thread.

    2016-09-16 11:57:45:309 - [debug] [Instruments] [INST STDERR] Instruments Usage Error: Specified target process is invalid: com.bytearc.SafariLauncher
    instruments, version 7.3 (60133)
    usage: instruments [-t template] [-D document] [-l timeLimit] [-i #] [-w device] [[-p pid] | [application [-e variable value] [argument ...]]]

    2016-09-16 11:57:45:320 - [debug] [Instruments] Instruments exited with code 255

    2016-09-16 11:57:45:321 - [Instruments] Error launching instruments: Instruments crashed on startup
```

Any help will be really appreciated

Xcode 7.3, 8.0
Appium 1.5.3
IOS version 8.0, 8.1,8.2, 9.2,9.3

```
    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "iOS");                                                           
    testStepMessage("Platform Name: iOS");                                                                        
    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, "9.2");                                
    testStepMessage("Platform Version: 9.3.1");                                                                 
    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "iPhone");                            
    testStepMessage("Device Name: iPhone 6s");        
    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.UDID, "Device UDID");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue always remain with the unstable version of Appium. What i did, i upgraded appium to 1.5.3 and Xcode 8.

Then i went to this forum

https://discuss.appium.io/t/bad-app-error-randomly-with-correct-path-and-valid-ipa-file/10191

and found that most of the issues arise due to appium.

Hope it help others too.